# How do I support ETags in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, etag

How do I support ETags in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

[@Elijah Glover's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/937685/592958) is part of the answer, but not really complete.   This will set the ETag, but you're not getting the benefits of ETags without checking it on the server side.  You do that with:

```
var requestedETag = Request.Headers["If-None-Match"];
if (requestedETag == eTagOfContentToBeReturned)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotModified);
```

Also, another tip is that you need to set the cacheability of the response, otherwise by default it's "private" and the ETag won't be set in the response:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndPrivate);
```

So a full example:

```
public ActionResult Test304(string input)
{
    var requestedETag = Request.Headers["If-None-Match"];
    var responseETag = LookupEtagFromInput(input); // lookup or generate etag however you want
    if (requestedETag == responseETag)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotModified);

    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.ServerAndPrivate);
    Response.Cache.SetETag(responseETag);
    return GetResponse(input); // do whatever work you need to obtain the result
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, for those looking to implement this, I would recommend implementing an abstract ActionFilter that implements this testing logic, and an abstract method called "abstract string CalculateEtag(HttpRequest)", subclassing it for each case where you need Etag support. This will keep your Actions methods "skinny" and make testing etag generation easier.

Comment: what is store in eTagOfContentToBeReturned ? how to generate etag for each action ?

Answer (score 30):

ETAG's in MVC are the same as WebForms or HttpHandlers.

You need a way of creating the ETAG value, the best way I have found is using a File MD5 or [ShortGuid](http://www.singular.co.nz/blog/archive/2007/12/20/shortguid-a-shorter-and-url-friendly-guid-in-c-sharp.aspx).

Since .net accepts a string as a ETAG, you can set it easily using

```
String etag = GetETagValue(); //e.g. "00amyWGct0y_ze4lIsj2Mw"
Response.Cache.SetETag(etag);
```

Video from [MIX](http://videos.visitmix.com/MIX09/T64M), at the end they use ETAG's with REST

Comment: I think this is wrong! because adding a static ETag would be like saying that your content will never change. The idea of ETags is to let the browser know that the content has changed, similar to expiration headers..

Comment: I think the harcoded value is for illustration purposes only... you can create something on the fly and change it.

Comment: Indeed. The very mention of using MD5 suggests it is calculated (perhaps only when it is changed or on the fly every time) and returned. It's clearly not a suggestion to use a static value.

Comment: The video link is not available anymore.