# MVC database images aren't being cached

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image

I am saving my images in my database, and retrieving them with the following code

```
 var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(image.Content);
 var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64); 

 <div class="img">
   <a><img src="@imgSrc"></a>
 </div>
```

the problem is, that every time I refresh the page, they are being downloaded again. How can I store them in cache?

Comment: If you marked your action with [OutputCacheAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) and provide duration for caching response then browser will cache your view contents.

Comment: given you embed your image (base64 encoded) within the page you serve to the browser, the browser cannot cache the single image (it can cache the whole result of a request, not just a part of it as your base64 image is in this case. If you force the browser asking for a separate resource (as in a common `<img src="something">` tag, you can set the cache attribute in the response header

Answer (score 1):

Base64 image cannot be cached by client browser as the image **data** is itself embeded in the src, unlike a **resource** that can be requested via a HTTP request.

Scenario A ("normal" image):

1. Load the page in browser
2. Browser read the image tag and make a request @ "src" to retrieve the **resource**
3. Web server responds to the request by providing the **resource**
4. Browser render the image

Scenario B (base64 image):

1. Load the page in browser
2. Browser read the image tag and because the base64 **data** already describe how the image should look like, the browser happily render it without making a request to web server again.

Tips: You can try to save the page by right-click then "Save as.." and observe the output. The base64 image is embeded in the html as **data** itself but not as a **resource** in another folder.

P/S: The caching method mentioned by @mmushtaq is server-side caching and might be useful if you're retriving the base64 data `image.Content` via ActionResult.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <staticContent>
<clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365:00:00" />
</staticContent>
```

add this line in Web.config file inside system.webServer for static content caching and also use [ETag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937668/how-do-i-support-etags-in-asp-net-mvc) filter in action.

Hopefully this caching process will help you.